# Parse complex string to parent/child array with PHP

Tags: php, parsing

Here is a sample of a string.

```
a (b, c(d and/or e, f, g), h, i[j, k]), l (m, n(o, p[q, r{s or t,u}, v]), w)
```

I need parse this into something like this:

```
{
-a
    -b
    -c
        -d 
        -and/or
        -e
        -f
        -g
    -h
    -i
        -j
        -k
-l
    -m
    -n
        -o
        -p
            -q
            -r
                -s
                -t
                -or
                -u
            -v
    -w
}
```

I started messing with some regex but it got ugly real quick. Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not consequent. Sometimes you use (), then {}, then []... ;-)

Comment: In addition to what thedom mentioned, to create parser, you need to define precise rules, that parser should run with. Without these rules, no one will be able to answer correctly to your question. For now, we can just guess what it is, that you want to achieve.

Comment: thedom, I know they are inconsistent.

@Deele, I'm parsing lists of ingredients into a parent/child structure. The top level items can have nested children wrapped in (), [], or {}. In most cases, the structure will be level1( level2[ level3{ level 4}])

Comment: @user3734597 see answers and don't forget to mark answer that works for you, as best answer, so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue about your rules, but this code basically will do the job

```
<?php
$string = 'a (b, c(d and/or e, f, g), h, i[j, k]), l (m, n(o, p[q, r{s or t,u}, v]), w)';
$indentLevel = 0;
$out = '';
echo '{'."\n";
// Split string into array of characters (AFAIK, that is basically how every parser works out there) and iterate over it
foreach (str_split($string) as $x) {
    // Determine if this character is string terminator or not
    $isTerminator = in_array($x, array(' ', ',', '(', '[', '{', ')', ']', '}'));
    // Output, because of string terminator, but only if output has something in it
    if ($isTerminator && strlen($out) > 0) {
        echo str_repeat("\t", $indentLevel).'-'.$out."\n";
        $out = '';
    }
    // Add to output (multiple character string support), if this is not string terminator
    elseif (!$isTerminator) {
        $out .= $x;
    }
    // Increase indent, because of brackets
    if (in_array($x, array('(', '[', '{'))) {
        $indentLevel++;
    }
    // Decrease indent, because of brackets
    elseif (in_array($x, array(')', ']', '}'))) {
        $indentLevel--;
    }
    // This is how you can tell that there is bracket count mismatch
    if ($indentLevel < 0) {
        die('Syntax error');
    }
}
echo '}'."\n";
```

Just note, that I added multiple character support for string, that was not requested, but I thought, it would better show the basic idea.

I hope you get basic idea and you will be able to continue expanding this code, into parser of your specific need.

Answer (score 0):

Not winning any beauty contests, but working:

```
<?php
$s = 'a (b, c(d and/or e, f, g), h, i[j, k]), l (m, n(o, p[q, r{s or t,u}, v]), w)';

$chars = str_split($s);

$sep   = array(',', ' ');
$open  = array('(', '[', '{');
$close = array(')', ']', '}');

function parse($s)
{
    global $sep, $open, $close;

    $chars   = str_split($s);
    $arr     = array();
    $collect = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($chars); $i++) {
        $c = $chars[$i];

        if (in_array($c, $open)) {
            $parens = 1;
            $inner  = '';
            do {
                $i++;
                $ch = $chars[$i];
                if (in_array($ch, $open)) {
                    $parens++;
                } elseif (in_array($ch, $close)) {
                    $parens--;
                }
                if ($parens > 0) {
                    $inner .= $ch;
                }
            } while ($parens > 0);

            if ($collect) {
                $arr[] = '-'.$collect;
            }
            $arr[]   = parse($inner);
            $collect = '';
            continue;
        }

        if (in_array($c, $sep)) {
            if ($collect == '') {
                continue;
            }
            $arr[]   = '-'.$collect;
            $collect = '';
        } else {
            $collect .= $c;
        }
    }

    if ($collect) {
        $arr[] = '-'.$collect;
    }

    return $arr;
}

print_r(parse($s));
```

Comment: It is not exactly what OP requested, but because of vague OP question, I will not lower score of this answer.

Comment: Output formatting is another step after this. I guessed he only wanted the parser.